# Dealing with additional kwargs in Django models

Tags: django, django-models, keyword-argument

I want to pass some parameters with `kwargs` to `get_or_create()` function in Django models but if there are some additional key-values in `kwargs` that do not exist in models, an error will apear. Is there any way to pass the dictionary and the function itself handles the additional keys?

Comment: Do you use forms? Please attach some code how do you try it.

Comment: No, I don't use forms. I have not implemented it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in Django source code you can find a better solution but, you also can create a function to remove extra keys from your data.

```
def remove_extra_keys(model, data: dict) -> dict:
    for filed_name in data:  # <- possibly for better reading u can use here data.keys()
        if not getattr(model, filed_name, None):
            data.pop(filed_name)
    return data

p = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(**remove_extra_keys(model=MyModel, data=my_data))
```

Comment: better to use Django forms for things like this.